# Get all GPS location points of a given route ( PHP )

Tags: php, gps, maps

I was searching a method to get all GPS coordinates of a given route **without** using Google maps JS library, since I wanted to get data on server end.

> So I have figured it out and ***posted the solution as an answer***. Hope this will be useful for somebody :)

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Google Directions API you can get the "overview_polyline" of a route. And through a polyline decoder you can get all the GPS coordinates on the given route.

Example link :-
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Panadura&destination=Moratuwa&key=YOUR_KEY

above link will return all the steps as a json response and at the end of the response there's a element named "overview_polyline" ;

Example response :-

```
"overview_polyline": {
            "points": "_p_h@ilzfNQtAWOiAk@c@OeAJgBn@eAj@cAf@wChBo@f@OXGf@GLKFWFBz@TlAJj@b@jARt@Hv@R`BRdANx@LZz@fBv@tAb@n@Zt@d@pAd@rADNH`@Vn@TV`@ZtAlAf@x@Jh@@^?zAQhBWrBMrBAl@G~@Mr@On@s@`BU|AKxAHv@Az@KjBi@~DEp@Dl@@h@A\\GtAF`@Vd@FZAl@KhAE\\f@Xf@^RVP^?v@MrASfECzD?fCCpC@La@BiAFoAFmCPoBPuCb@_ARcAVy@Xo@\\_At@uAnA}AnAOLABCBA@]|@Ib@Gx@UlDCdBWnGQpCHj@BJ@BBFALEDYvBWdAM\\k@xAs@pAs@dAi@n@oBjBoAbA}@h@SHaL|CiWnHgLzCuD`A{Cl@aKlB_BX{A^kFvA}@XyEfBoBr@uBv@gDnA{E|A{GrBmHdBmD|@aIzBkBf@mCj@sB^{Ch@mCh@yD|@}GjB_EnAoDbAoCp@oDz@cDx@gDv@gIhBoB^cALuAN}ALmCLeDDaGAoB@iBHaEZyBX{Fp@eFl@uAJeBDgA?kACaAGkAMyAYeBa@cCy@wHqCwAa@mEs@mC_@{CUmIc@oCIw@IsAW}Bc@IBK?IEGK?KBK\\[JOV{@p@yC?u@K_BSsBCk@?iCFm@@QEs@GYS[K[A]B]As@K_A?oA@cA"
        },
```

using a polyline decoder you can get the all GPS coordinates. There are number of polyline decoders available on the internet.

Here are some,

1. Javascript : https://github.com/mapbox/polyline
2. PHP : https://github.com/dyaaj/polyline-encoder
3. Google Maps : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

> Make sure to replace \\ (double backslash) into \ (single backslash) in polyline string.

if you still want to get points according to specific distance split ( example: 200m ) you may can write a code to measure distance on adjacent locations and build up a points array by removing unwanted points.